# mysql error when import sql file access denied

Tags: mysql

As in the title i get:

Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' to database 'dbname'

when i try to import a mysql file as below:

mysql -u xxxx -p dbname < mysql_update

if i do a show privileges inside the database accessin with xxxx i get this result:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for tacticalcustom@localhost                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'xxxx'@'localhost'                                           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.* TO 'xxxx'@'localhost'                           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.* TO 'xxxx'@'localhost'                           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.`dbname` TO 'xxxx'@'localhost'                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

did i miss something?

Comment: Forget the "import" file, if you try:
mysql -u xxxx -p
and then type your password, do you get into the mysql client? If yes then what happns when you try 
USE dbname

Comment: everything works, i had access to the db and changed to the dbname with USE, but i still can't import with xxxx user